# Get User's Security Groups using PHP LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I want to query AD to get specific user information using LDAP. Currently I am having to do sub-searches with LDAP to narrow down the list of users returned from my initial search.

Is there a way to query AD to get only the user logging in with their username and password so that there is not an entire array of users exposed to PHP in the resultset?

Currently I have:

```
public function authenticate_user($user, $pass)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    try
    {
        $this->userConn = ldap_connect($this->domain);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo "Can't connect to ActiveDirectory: " . $e->GetMessage();
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
    }

    ldap_set_option( $this->userConn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 ); // Recommended for AD
    ldap_set_option( $this->userConn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0 );

    try
    {
        ldap_bind($this->userConn, $user . $this->account_suffix, $pass);
        $this->userBinding = ldap_read($this->userConn, $this->base_dn, '(OU="Domain Users")');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return $e->GetMessage();
    }
    return 'Authenticated';
}

public function get_user_info()
{
    $sn = substr($this->user, 1, strlen($this->user));

    try
    {       
                $result = ldap_search($this->userConn, $this->base_dn, "CN=Domain Admins"); 
    }
        catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return "Can't find users ldap_search " . $e->GetMessage();
    }
    if (isSet($result))
    {
        $member_list = ldap_get_entries($this->userConn, $result);
        if (isSet($member_list) && is_array($member_list))
        {
            // return $member_list;
            $member_details = $this->get_members($member_list);
        }
        else
        {
            ldap_close($this->userConn);
            return FALSE;
        }
        ldap_close($this->userConn);
        return $member_details;

    }
    else
    {   
        ldap_close($this->userConn);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid having to get an array of users back and then cycle through the array in PHP and perform another `ldap_search`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well after poking the code a bit, I found that changing the `ldap_search`  in `function get_user_info()` from  `$result = ldap_search($this->userConn, $this->base_dn, "CN=Domain Admins");`  to  `$result = ldap_search($this->userConn, $this->base_dn, "mail=" . $email);` Where `$email` is the login used.